# mysql count distinct value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have trouble wondering how do I count distinct value. using if on the select column

I have SQLFIDDLE here

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6bfb9/3

Records shows:

```
create table team_record (
  id tinyint,
  project_id int,
  position varchar(45)
  );

insert into team_record values
(1,1, 'Junior1'),
(2,1, 'Junior1'),
(3,1, 'Junior2'),
(4,1, 'Junior3'),
(5,1, 'Senior1'),
(6,1, 'Senior1'),
(8,1, 'Senior2'),
(9,1, 'Senior2'),
(10,1,'Senior3'),
(11,1, 'Senior3'),
(12,1, 'Senior3')
```

I need to count all distinct value, between Junior and Senior column.

all same value would count as 1.

I need to see result something like this.

```
PROJECT_ID  SENIOR_TOTAL    JUNIOR_TOTAL
1                3              3
```

mysql query is this. but this is not a query to get the result above.

```
SELECT 
    `team_record`.`project_id`,
    `position`,       
    SUM(IF(position LIKE 'Senior%',
        1,
        0)) AS `Senior_Total`,
    SUM(IF(position LIKE 'Junior%',
        1,
        0)) AS `Junior_Total`
FROM
    (`team_record`)        
WHERE
    project_id = '1'        
GROUP BY `team_record`.`project_id`
```

maybe you could help me fix my query above to get the result I need.

thanks

Comment: This would be much simpler (and faster) if you separated the numeric component out to another column

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you want this:

```
SELECT 
   project_id,
   COUNT(DISTINCT CASE when position LIKE 'Senior%' THEN position END) Senior_Total,
   COUNT(DISTINCT CASE when position LIKE 'Junior%' THEN position END) Junior_Total
FROM team_record
WHERE project_id = 1
GROUP BY project_id
```

The CASE will return a null if the WHEN is false (ie `ELSE NULL` is the default, which I omitted for brevity), and nulls aren't counted in DISTINCT.

Also, unnecessary back ticks, brackets and qualification removed.